# How do I get my smaller text to be below my larger text?

Tags: html

This is what I am working on. As you can see, my smaller text is right beside my bigger text. I want it below. I am new to coding btw! this is my html code:

```html
<body>
    <h1 id="title">
      <i class="fas fa-cloud-moon"></i>  edgenuity  <i class="fas fa-cloud-moon"></i>
      <font size="+2">Get those stupid classes done. Find the answers here.</font> 
    </h1>
  </body>
```

Comment: Add a <br> where you want the line jump

Comment: Please [don't use profanity on SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites) or include links to NSFW content.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.page-title {
       display: block;
       margin-top: 0;
       margin-bottom: .5rem;
       font-size: 2rem;
       color: #000;
    }
    .subtitle {
      display: block;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: .5rem;
      color: gray;
    }
```

```html
<h1 id="title">
  <p class="page-title"><i class="fas fa-cloud-moon"></i>   edgenuity  <i class="fas fa-cloud-moon"></i>
  </p>
  <p class="subtitle">Get those stupid classes done. Find the answers here.</p>
</h1>
```

first of all your html markup is not valid. font tag is deprecated.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)

> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.

so for displaying title above of subtitle.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order:

```js
<body>
    <h1 id="title">      
      <font size="+2">Get those stupid classes done. Find the answers here.</font> 
      <i class="fas fa-cloud-moon"></i>  edgenuity  <i class="fas fa-cloud-moon"></i>
    </h1>
 
  </body>
```

Comment: that just put my small text above it but still beside it, I want my little text completely below my big text

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `<i>` is inline element. You should use block element for that.
Read about [inline and block elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp).

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
<body>
    <h1 id="title">
        <p>
            <i class="fas fa-cloud-moon"></i>  
            some text 
            <i class="fas fa-cloud-moon"> </i>
        </p>
        <p>
            <font size="+2">
                Get those  classes done. Find the answers here.
            </font> 
         </p>
     </h1>
     
 </body>
```